# Xamarin Forms error: Could not resolve type with token 01000047

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dll

I have a custom dll in my project made in Visual Basic but when I try to run a function it returns this error: Could not resolve type with token 01000047 from typeref (expected class 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')

Is there something I'm missing? I added the dll in the references for all projects and installed the Visual Basic nuget package.

The code is as follows:

```
    string aResult;
    string Response;
    string ErrorText;
    long SelfCareID;
    string FullName;
    public Api api;
    public string loginResponse;
    public string registerResponse;
    public string createResponse;
    public string otpCode;
    public SmartMeterVM()
    {
        api = new Api();
        LoginCommand = new Command(LoginTestButton);
    }

    public Command LoginCommand { get; set; }
 
    public void LoginCheck(UserModel userData)
    {
        ErrorText = "Something";
        SelfCareID = 12389471823749;
        FullName = "Some full";
        try
        {
           loginResponse = api.AccUpdate(userData.idNumber, 2, ref SelfCareID,  ref FullName,  ref ErrorText);

            if (loginResponse.ToLower() == "success")
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(loginResponse.ToLower(), "Success", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(ErrorText);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(ex.Message, "Error","Ok");
        }
    

        return;
    }


public void LoginTestButton()
        {
            var userTestData = new UserModel
            {
                idNumber = "01049496"
            };
            LoginCheck(userTestData);
        }
```

UPDATE: I tried updating all the nuget packages but still no change. Is it just not possible to use a dll made in visual basic in xamarin?

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild on your complete solution
If that doesn't work; manually delete the bin and obj folders from each project folder and rebuild

Comment: The version of Net on machine and the version of Net that was used to build the Visual Basic nuget package are not the same.  You need to rebuild the nuget package.

Comment: @jdweng how do I rebuild the Visual Basic nuget package? My project is using .Net Standard 2.0

Comment: Is it possible to add a library or link to include Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime?

Comment: I am afraid not

Comment: Is the issue perhaps related to the custom dll in the project? I added it by going to Project -> Add Project Reference then browsed to my dll. Was there another step I needed to do?

Comment: You could test the custom dll in other projects to see if the error persists or create a new test custom dll with simple function to test if the binding is working.

Answer (score 0):

To rebuild Nuget package.

First, right click the project and click "manage Nuget packages" to manage your Nuget packages.

And then, find the package you want to rebuild(Microsoft.VisualBasic in this project).

At last, uninstall it and install the lasted version.

Comment: try change your visualbasic package version to 10.0.0

Comment: I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the visualbasic to 10.0.0 then deleted the bin and obj files from all project folders problem still persists

Comment: Could you offer a sample project to show more detail information ?